# jQuery - from an HTML string, find all elements with a given data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Using jQuery, I am trying to find all elements with a `data-inject` attribute from an HTML string returned from the server. Here's an example HTML string:

```
var html = '<div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div data-inject="ViewModel1" class="span12"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div data-inject="ViewModel2" class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom"></div>';
```

I can't seem to find a way to get both `div`s and the problem seems to be the fact that I'm starting with a HTML string.

**[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2qYH/4/)** showing that just querying the DOM with `$('[data-inject]')` returns the two elements as expected. However, querying the HTML string with `$('[data-inject]', html)` only returns one element (the `ViewModel1` element).

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to get the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you don't have a root element. Just temporarily use wrapAll during the query.

```
var html = '<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row-fluid"><div data-inject="TowerLogsViewModel" class="span12"></div></div></div><div data-inject="TowerLogFormViewModel" class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom"></div>';
var $html = $(html);

$('[data-inject]', $html.wrapAll($('<div>')).parent()).each(function (ix, el) {
    console.log($(el).data('inject'));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K3BWm/)**

Due to the absence of root element the collection this will find `data-inject` from the first element in the collection i.e `<div class="container-fluid">` so you get only one. if you use filter you will get only the other one. Hence wrap them temporarily.

Comment: Can you please confirm/describe what line 2 does?  Does jQuery convert the string into actual objects, still not bound to the DOM?